# List item IDs and GUIDs after restoring from recycle bin

Tags: list-item, guid, recycle-bin

I want to know if we delete List items and then restore same items from recycle bin, then they will be restored with new IDs and GUIDs or with the old IDs as before deleting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restored items will have the original IDs and Unique IDs.

Comment: You mean old IDs as before deleting ? What about GUIDs

Comment: SPListItem.ID (int) and SPListItem.UniqueID (Guid) will retain the values and will be same as the old ones.